# The excerpt doesn't work for Wordpress default post but does work for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

the excerpt function not work in my custom post template using Wordpress default posts in the query loop, but they work fine with custom post type.

I enabled the display of excerpt by checking the "excerpt" option in the post options fields.

I also added "add_post_type_support('page' 'excerpt')" in my function.php file but it doesn't working.

I suspect a problem coming from the database because the excerpts are displayed when I test the website locally with Xampp.

Here is a snippet of the code used in my page template:

```
<div class="container">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-mg-9 mp-blog" style="padding-right: 24px;">

                    
                          <div class="row">

                                <?php
                                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                                $args = array(
                                  'post_type'=>'post', // Your post type name
                                  'posts_per_page' => 6,
                                  'cat' => 26,
                                  'paged' => $paged,
                                );
                                
                                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>


                     <?php the_excerpt();?>


                     <?php endwhile;
          
                  $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    ?>
    <div class="custom_pagination">   
    <?php
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« précédent'),
            'next_text'    => __('suivant »'),
        ));?>
    </div>
    <?php }    
}
wp_reset_postdata();?>
    

              </div>


              </div><!-------------- end of col-8 ------------------>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-mg-3" style="padding: 0;">
                  <div id="tching" class="blog_right_sidebar" style="padding: 0 15px;">
                      <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: So it works on your local development server but it doesn't work on the production server? hmm! Interesting! Is it only ``` the_excerpt() ``` that doesn't work or other functions such as ```the_title()``` or ```the_permalink()``` don't work either?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the_title() and the_permalink() are working.

Comment: The only possibility that i can think of at the moment is that, ```the_excerpt()``` might be empty and doesn't contain any value.

Comment: Yes I tested with a var_dump(), and the result is null.